# Starting from a template to generate ODT document with JAVA

Tags: java, templates, report, odt, odfdom

I have tried a few APIs : JopenDocument and ODFDOM and both of them don't offer what i'm looking for.

I want to be able to do the following :

- Start from a template .
- Process this template with JAVA to generate ODT/Docx reports.

I need those two functionality : Adding Images dynamically and tables .

JopenDocument offers almost all of this, but lacks adding images .

Are there any other API to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found **XdocReport** https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/ and it does exactly what i'm looking for with complete documentation and samples.

Answer (score 2):

Other options you haven't come across:

- [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) (commercial)
- [JOD Reports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) (opensource, but a bit
  out of date)

Both meet your requirements:

- use documents as templates
- Java API
- ODT/DOCX output
- Add images
- Add tables

Please note I work for Docmosis.

I hope that helps.